# Trim excel table column names in Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, office-scripts

We have an Azure Logic app that reads an excelfile from sharepoint and inserts the rows into a sql db. Sometimes the column names in the excel file contains leading and/or trailing white spaces witch makes the insert fail because the column names in the Insert Row action wont match the column names in the file. What would be the best way to remove leading and trailing white spaces from column names in an Azure Logic app?
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking you could use the excel TRIM formula to do some cleanup prior to insertion. One idea is to use an office script to create a new worksheet with a spilled range for the header - eg. on the new sheet in A1 put this formula =TRIM(Sheet1!A1:Z1). Do something similar for the remaining data then pull from the new worksheet. Would something like that work? Are you hoping to keep the text cleanup/trimming in the Logic app?

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes that sounds like a good solution, I was hoping to do it in the Logic app. I tried to add an Excel Run script action but do not understand how to write the script, there are no scripts available from the drop down and when I try to type some script in the Script-textbox I get:
 Error code: 'BadRequest', Message: 'Unable to parse script reference'
(even though the script is a valid Office script, I found some examples online)
Do I have to append the script to the file somehow to find it in the drop down? Sry for the questions, I am new to Logic Apps and Office scripts...

Comment: you will need to create an Office Script in Excel for the web first. After it is created it should be available for selection in the Excel Run Script action via the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is that you can use the `replace` expression by taking the name variable in the `compose` connector. Here is my workflow -

[image]

I'm using the below dynamic expression for replacing the white space

```
replace(variables('Name'),' ','')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I am wondering if the name variable contains the content of the cells or if it is the headernames? Because our problem is only with the headers, (and how to access the headernames in the logic app). Ideally we would like to trim/replace only the header names. In your example, does the Name-variable only contain the headernames and how do you set that variable?

Comment: Name variable contains all the Name column values

Comment: To set the variable you need to initialize the variable by using `Initialize variable` connector with its name, mentioning the datatype of that column and then using `set variable` connector mapping to the header of the column that we want to perform operations on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built-in replace, you could add a Flow step that pulls the data out from Excel via an Office Script. The Office Script can get the range/table and perform the cleanup just on the headers, then return the result to the next step in the Flow. You can get as creative with the details as you need to be:

[image]

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  const table = workbook.getTable("DemoTable");
  const headersAndValues = table.getRange().getValues();
  cleanup(headersAndValues[0] as string[]);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(headersAndValues));
  return headersAndValues;
}

function cleanup(data: string[]): string[] {
  data.forEach((val, index) => {
    data[index] = val.trim();
  })
}
```

[image]